# is there good Angular Js + rails backend tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, frontend, backend

recently I read Micahel Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial.

It really works for me.

Now, I want to make front-end with Angular or Ember JS.

I plan to use rails as backend server with json.

please suggest any good tutorial or book in this situation.

thanks all of you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Railscast about Angularjs](http://railscasts.com/episodes/405-angularjs)

[Railscast about Emberjs Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/408-ember-part-1) and [Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/410-ember-part-2)

This is nice [tutorial](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/2013/12/11/beginners-guide-to-angular-js-rails?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email)

Edit - After looking at all tutorials referenced in this post here is another [one](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/).

Comment: as this post is over a year old, can you recommend any other tutorials? I have found a few myself, and looked at all those referenced on this website.

Comment: I'm the author of the one linked in "This is a nice tutorial" (ghostwritten). If you'd like a more up-to-date tutorial that covers Angular 2, you might want to try [this one](https://www.angularonrails.com/angular-2-tour-heroes-tutorial-rails-backend/).

Answer (score 13):

There's a paid one here. I've only watched the first video about the Rails part, and it was straightforward.
[egghead.io AngularJS/Rails TODO API](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-rails-todo-api-part-1)

Others:

- [AngularJS with Rails 4 Blog App Tutorial by Adam
  Anderson](http://asanderson.org/posts/2013/06/03/bootstrapping-angular-rails-part-1.html)
- [Same thing but for a stockmarket app, by Alexander Potrykus](http://alexpotrykus.com/blog/2013/12/07/angularjs-with-rails-4-part-1/)
- http://start.jcolemorrison.com/setting-up-an-angularjs-and-rails-4-1-project/
- http://www.honeybadger.io/blog/2013/12/11/beginners-guide-to-angular-js-rails
- https://shellycloud.com/blog/2013/10/how-to-integrate-angularjs-with-rails-4
- Same guy as previous, http://mkwiatkowski.github.io/angularjs-rails4-trug-presentation/#3

More tips than tutorial:

- http://codetunes.com/2014/5-tips-on-how-to-use-angularjs-with-rails-that-changed-how-we-work/
- http://www.slatestudio.com/blog/p/better-programming-with-ruby-on-rails-and-angularjs

Comment: as this post is over a year old, can you recommend any other tutorials? I have found a few myself, and looked at all those referenced on this website.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I didn't go far down that path, so I haven't looked. Feel free to post what you found though, there's probably people still looking at these questions.